# allowing only alphabets in text box using java script

Tags: javascript, html

I want to allow only alphabets in textbox using JavaScript
I used the code:

```
var nam=f.nm.value;
if(!isNaN(nam))  
    region.innerHTML="alphabets only";
```

It is not working and allows numbers as well. How can i fix this?

Comment: http://www.dotnetlearners.com/javascript/allow%20only%20alphabets%20in%20a%20textbox%20using%20javascript.aspx

Comment: Use HTML5 `pattern` attribute..

Answer (score 13):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>allwon only alphabets in textbox using JavaScript</title>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
            try {
                if (window.event) {
                    var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
                }
                else if (e) {
                    var charCode = e.which;
                }
                else { return true; }
                if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert(err.Description);
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event,this);" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

just use onkeypress event like below:

```
<input type="text" name="onlyalphabet" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)">
```

Answer (score 7):

From kosare comments, i have create an demo http://jsbin.com/aTUMeMAV/2/

HTML

```
      <form name="f" onsubmit="return onlyAlphabets()">
         <input type="text" name="nm">
         <div id="notification"></div>
         <input type="submit">
      </form>
```

javascript

```
  function onlyAlphabets() {

  var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
  if (regex.test(document.f.nm.value)) {

      //document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML = "Watching.. Everything is Alphabet now";
      return true;
  } else {
      document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML = "Alphabets Only";
      return false;
  }


}
```

Comment: ya its okay but i want output like after entering name with numbers its have show beside the text box alphabets only after submitting

Comment: great solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use HTML5 pattern attribute to do this:

```
<form>
    <input type='text' pattern='[A-Za-z\\s]*'/>
</form>
```

If the user enters an input that conflicts with the pattern, it will show an error dialogue automatically.

Comment: its allowing numbers too and not showing error for numbers in combination with alphabets

Comment: Works for me. Make sure your input tag is in a form. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/x3VnW/

Comment: copy paste numeric character is also accepted by this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
        return (e.charCode > 64 && e.charCode < 91) || (e.charCode > 96 && e.charCode < 123) || e.charCode == 32;   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**:::::HTML:::::**

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return lettersValidate(event)" />
```

**Only letters no spaces**

**::::JS::::::::**

```
// ===================== Allow - Only Letters ===============================================================

function lettersValidate(key) {
    var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;

    if ((keycode > 64 && keycode < 91) || (keycode > 96 && keycode < 123))  
    {     
           return true;    
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
         
}
```