# Regular Expression: Allow only characters a-z, A-Z

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs

**ExtJS 5.1**

Let's say I have an example like that, I want user's name-surname so I don't want any numbers or special chars, I tried so many possibilities but couldn't make it:

```
var controller=this;
var refs = controller.getReferences();
var exp = '/^([^0-9]*)$/';

onButtonClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    if(refs.nameSurname.value.match(exp)){
        Ext.Msg.alert('ERROR', 'BlaBla');
    }
}
```

With this code, I have no error when i enter a number to text field...

Thank you.

Comment: `var exp = /^[^0-9]*$/;` - remove the single quotes.

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z+]$/`

Comment: it didnt work again, "!= null" is necessary? because i think i have problems on if condition.. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: This question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783093/allowing-only-alphabets-in-text-box-using-java-script

Comment: `if(!(/^[^0-9]*$/.test(refs.nameSurname.value))){` ?

Comment: The pattern and the title are really misleading: what is your intent? Note that `^[^0-9]*$` only disallows a digit in the input. It does not restrict to just ASCII letters. **Please clarify**.

Comment: it worked ty @WiktorStribiżew ,normally i had used 'test' but it gave me error 'no method like test' but now worked.

Comment: Ty, the answer from that page also worked. @Nofi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming you need to actually match a string that has no digits**...

You should not enclose the regex literal with single quotes, remove them. You do not need the capture group, you can remove `(` and `)`.

Use

```
var exp = /^[^0-9]*$/;
```

Now, to check if a string matches a regex, you will be safer using a [**`RegExp#test()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

See the demo below:

```js
var refs_nameSurname = "Som8ehere";
if(!(/^[^0-9]*$/.test(refs_nameSurname))){
        console.log('ERROR');
}
```

**However,** you can reverse the logic, and show an error once a digit is found inside a string (simpler!):

```js
var refs_nameSurname = "Somehere12";
if(/[0-9]/.test(refs_nameSurname)){
        console.log('ERROR');
}
```