# Force input pattern with only letter

Tags: javascript, function, validation, input

I need a function that forces an input type with only letter, number is not allowed. I still have this function and i want to add this new function.   Can you please help me?

```
<script>

    function valida() {

        if ($('#cut').val() == '') {
            alert("u must insert something");
            $('#cut').addClass("ui-state-error");
            return false;

        }
        if ($('#tas').val() == '') {
            alert(u must insert something");
            $('#tas').addClass("ui-state-error");
            return false;

        }
        if ($('#nom').val() == '') {
            alert("u must insert something");
            $('#nom').addClass("ui-state-error");
            return false;

        }


    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. `checkAlphabets()` will check either entered value is alfabates or not

```
<script>
    function checkAlphabets(e) {
        try {
            if (window.event) {
                var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
            }
            else if (e) {
                var charCode = e.which;
            } else { 
                return true; 
            }

            if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err.Description);
        }
    }

    function validate() {

        if ($('#cut').val() == '') {
            alert("u must insert something");
            $('#cut').addClass("ui-state-error");
            return false;

        }
        if ($('#tas').val() == '') {
            alert(u must insert something");
            $('#tas').addClass("ui-state-error");
            return false;

        }
        if ($('#nom').val() == '') {
            alert("u must insert something");
            $('#nom').addClass("ui-state-error");
            return false;
        }
        if (checkAlphabets($('#nom').val()) == false) {
            alert("u must insert something");
            $('#nom').addClass("ui-state-error");
            return false;   
        }
    }
</script>
```

Ref: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783093/allowing-only-alphabets-in-text-box-using-java-script)