# How to allow only alphabets in ion_input in ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I want my ion-input to allow only alphabets, I'm trying it by using pattern in ionic 2 (typescript) but it is not working, It's accepting special characters and numerics and even emoji's. Please help me how should I only accept alphabets via ion-input.

Comment: Try this `<ion-input pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" ></ion-input>`

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783093/allowing-only-alphabets-in-text-box-using-java-script) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

Comment: @hrdkisback i already have tried using  <ion-input pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" ></ion-input> but it doesn't work in android.

Comment: In `ios` is it works or not?

Comment: @hrdkisback I haven't tested it in ios yet. But I desperately want it to work in android first.

Comment: How do you check it's works or not? i mean on which condition you are checking? put some code you tried.

Comment: <ion-input [(ngModel)]="meter_no" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"type="text">---</ion-input>  
It should only allow alphabet but when I run it, It also allow numeric and special characters .

Comment: `pattern` still allows all input, it just sets the `invalid` flag

Comment: Try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-input-mask